# Diagonal element for covariance matrix not 1 pandas/numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, covariance

I have the following dataframe:

```
   A  B
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8
```

I wish to calculate the covariance

```
a = df.iloc[:,0].values

b = df.iloc[:,1].values
```

Using numpy for cov as :

```
numpy.cov(a,b)
```

I get:

```
array([[ 1.66666667,  1.66666667],
   [ 1.66666667,  1.66666667]])
```

Shouldn't the diagonal elements be 1? How do I get the diagonal elements to 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they shouldn't. I think you might be confusing it with Correlation.
Correlation and Covariance are different.

What you see in the diagonals is simply the variance of the variables!
Wiki screenshot for the formulas -

[image]

[Wiki Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_correlation)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`pd.DataFrame.corr`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)
Also, no need to use Numpy here when the built in Pandas method does the job well for you.  Correlations will be one because you've normalized the different series by their respective standard deviations.

```
df.corr() 

     A    B
A  1.0  1.0
B  1.0  1.0
```

While [**`pd.DataFrame.cov`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html) gets you

```
df.cov()

          A         B
A  1.666667  1.666667
B  1.666667  1.666667
```

The other posters are correct.  We can see that performing the maths correctly, we get

```
df.cov().div(df.std()).div(df.std(), 0)

     A    B
A  1.0  1.0
B  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function that you are looking for should be numpy.corrcoef rather than numpy.cov .

The relationship between correlation matrix and covariance matris is as follows:

```
R[i,j] = C[i,j]/sqrt(C[i,i]*C[j,k])
```