# Why doesn't EmpiricalCovariance output a matrix with a constant diagonal?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, covariance

When using `EmpiricalCovariance` to develop a covariance matrix for high-dimensional data, I would expect the diagonal of this matrix (from the top-left to the bottom-right) to be all ones, as of course a variable is always going to perfectly correlate to itself. However, this is not the case. Why not?

Here is an example, plotted with a seaborns heatmap:
[image: Covariance matrix plotted as a heatmap. The diagonal from the top-left to the top-right is lighter than most of the rest of the data, but not the lightest points.]

As you can see, the diagonal is lighter than most of the data, however it's not as light as the lightest point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/covariance/empirical_covariance_.py#L200) of EmpiricalCovariance class and utility [function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/covariance/empirical_covariance_.py#L50) that it invokes, you see that `np.cov(data, bias=1)` is (almost) the same as `EmpiricalCovariance.fit(...).covariance_`.

Lets do some experiments:

```
from sklearn.covariance import EmpiricalCovariance
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)
data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
np.allclose(EmpiricalCovariance().fit(data).covariance_, np.cov(data.T, bias=1))
# returns True !
```

From the [numpy's official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) you could see that diagonal elements of covariance matrix are row-variances:

```
np.isclose(np.var(data[0]), np.cov(data, bias=1)[0][0])
# returns TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

See this related thread [from another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427238/diagonal-element-for-covariance-matrix-not-1-pandas-numpy/47427304#47427304)

In summary: what you see in the diagonals is the variance, not the correlation